# VB.net built in web browser not displaying

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

edit:  VB is not my primary language, but seems to be the most practical way to do what I need to do

I am trying to make a program that rotates through a series of PDFs and webpages in a full screen window.  I used this example ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666(v=vs.110).aspx ) as a base, but stripped out the menu options and added in the InfoboardMode sub to rotate through files in the dir folder.  I am failing to even get the webbrowser1 object to display, let alone the files rotating.  Please advise.

Thank you

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Security.Permissions


Public Class Form1


Private WithEvents webBrowser1 As WebBrowser
Private WithEvents pageTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    webBrowser1.GoHome()

    Controls.Add(webBrowser1)

    'webBrowser1.Navigate("c:\test\example.pdf")

End Sub

Public Sub Main()

End Sub

Public Sub InfoboardMode()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim counter1 As Integer = 0
    Dim dir As String = "c:\test"
    Dim FileCount = 1
    pageTimer.Interval = 20000

    Do While counter < FileCount
        Dim URLs() = New IO.DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray
        FileCount = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(dir).Count
        Dim link As String = "" + dir + "\" + URLs(counter).ToString
        webBrowser1.Navigate(link)
        pageTimer.Start()
        counter = counter + 1
        counter1 = counter1 + 1
        If counter >= FileCount Then
            counter = 0
        End If

        If counter1 = FileCount * 4 Then
            counter = FileCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    InfoboardMode()

End Sub
End Class
```

My result right now is a giant, borderless window, but nothing but gray.

Edit 2: Following Visual Vincent suggestions with no success

Comment: `Application.Run(New Form1)` cannot be used in this context. It probably throws an exception in the background that you do not see. Not saying this is the solution, but `Application.Run()` should **only** be used when the application first starts in order to view the first form.

Comment: Also, what happens if you do `Me.Controls.Add(webBrowser1)` instead of `Controls.AddRange(New Control() {webBrowser1})`?

Comment: And finally, using `Thread.Sleep()` on the UI thread will block it - this might actually be your problem. Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to do the rotating instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent I will make those suggested changes and report back shortly.  I won't be able to add it in comment, so I will edit the original post code

Comment: You're always supposed to edit when you change something. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent no success, see update.  Even if you have a suggestion on how to get passed the giant grey box

Comment: You have an infinite loop, that's why. You were supposed to get tid of that and use the timer's Tick event. I'm writing an answer.

Comment: I meant to say "...get **rid** of that..."

Comment: Has my answer provided a solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

The timer doesn't halt the current method for you. The reason it doesn't work is because you now have an infinite loop with no delay.

You are supposed to use the timer's `Tick` event which will be fired every `Interval` milliseconds (in your case every 20000 ms, or 20 s).

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim dir As String = "c:\test"
Dim FileCount As Integer = 1

Private Sub pageTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles pageTimer.Tick
    Dim URLs() As FileInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories) 'Why were you calling .ToArray() on an array?
    FileCount = URLs.Length 'Here you can just check the amount of items in the URLs array.

    Dim link As String = IO.Path.Combine(dir, URLs(counter).FullName)
    webBrowser1.Navigate(link)

    counter += 1
    If counter >= FileCount Then
        counter = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    pageTimer.Interval = 20000
    pageTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

By the way, **never** use `+` to concatenate strings. Always use the ampersand `&` -- but in this case I replaced the `link` logic with `IO.Path.Combine()` which is better to use when concatenating file paths.

I also removed `counter1` as it appears to be of no necessary use.

---

**Read more about timers on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).**